# Why doesn't the focal length of Viewport change upon zooming?

Tags: 3d-view

As far as I know, to "zoom" means to change the focal length of a camera. But no matter how much I zoom the Viewport (not a camera in the scene) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>MMB</kbd>, the `Focal Length` property shown in sidebar remains "50 mm". Does <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>MMB</kbd> actually dolly rather than zoom? Or am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>MMB</kbd> you don't zoom, but you dolly (by default):

[image]

Comment: Ok but when I press Shift+Ctrl, the status bar says MMB is "Dolly View" instead of "Zoom View" like when only Ctrl is pressed. Is there any difference?

Comment: @LaiYu-Hsuan when your default zoom method is set to Dolly they are the same, but when you set it to something different, ctrl-mmb will do that and shif-ctrl-mmb will dolly

Comment: Now it all makes sense. Thank you.